# Errors on 'concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client" with MERN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, mern, concurrently

First of all, I would like to apologize for the spelling mistakes, I'm not very good.

I have a problem whilethe starting my mern server... 
I want to run it with with "npm run dev". This command line execute "npm run server" and "npm run client".
Here's my errors :

C:\Users\Jérémy\Desktop\Rendu\MERN\MERN_d04>npm run dev

```
mern_d04@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\Jérémy\Desktop\Rendu\MERN\MERN_d04
concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"

[0] Error occurred when executing command: npm run server
[0] Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
[0]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
[0]     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
[1] Error occurred when executing command: npm run client
[1] Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
[1]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
[1]     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
[1] npm run client exited with code -4058
[0] npm run server exited with code -4058
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mern_d04@1.0.0 dev: `concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"`>npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mern_d04@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jérémy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-22T19_45_03_286Z-debug.log
```

And Here's, my root package.json :

```
{
  "name": "mern_d04",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm-install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "is-empty": "^1.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.10",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "validator": "^13.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

And here's my client package.json :

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried many things and, the most surprising thing is : it works on the computer of my friend but not mines. 
Please someone can help me? :)

EDIT : Node version : 13.0.0

EDIT : Found the solution. I "just" had a variable "C:\Windows\System32" in the environment variables :)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem.
for this code works, you can try this.. on your root package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index",
    "server": "nodemon index",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"cd client && npm start\""
  },
```

and then from root directory type npm **run dev**

Answer (score 0):

The node_modules are not compatible with your current systems. You may remove the node_modules folders at the root level AS WELL AS at the client level. Then you install both node_modules AGAIN.